# Определение типа элемента интерфейса по картинке

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Мне нужно определить тип элемента интерфейса. Есть набор изображений (120 штук примерно). Есть 10 элементов на экране, их координаты известны. Мне необходимо определить "тип" каждого элемента - сравнить его с каждой картинкой и найти точное совпадение (нужна не нейронная сеть, картинки и элемент совпадают почти целиком (могут немного отличаться из-за размера экрана). Если что, речь об одной онлайн-игре. Я думаю, что надо смотреть в сторону OpenCV, но он я думаю, он слишком сильно нагружает процессор. Есть какие-нибудь другие варианты? Или решение похожей задачи на OpenCV?

Comment: Могли бы Вы привести примеры изображений? Если они достаточно сильно отличаются, то решение вполне себе есть в openCV. Не очень понимаю, почему Вы так переживаете из-за нагруженного процессора. У Вас мобилка будет работать или на каком-то портативном устройстве? Так-то, почти любые действия, связанные с обработкой изображений будут затраными.